# MVC3 WebGrid showing custom class objects from model into columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I'm trying to show a model in a WebGrid which has one column with a custom class. Without using the "format:" parameter to customize the column in the WebGrid, can I add something to my custom class (something like a default cast= to show a custom text instead of the full class name in the WebGrid?
I tried implicit/explicit conversion operators to string or HtmlString without success...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Without using the "format:" parameter to customize the column in the
>   WebGrid, can I add something to my custom class (something like a
>   default cast= to show a custom text instead of the full class name in
>   the WebGrid?

AFAIK you should use a custom `format:` in the corresponding column.

Comment: Yes, I know too... but... I need to remember to use the "format" on each view, while if I add some generic cast to the class, it must be added only one time... much better if I need only text.
Also: it will enable sorting for that column... with only using the format, won't be sorted at all.

Comment: I agree with you. You may checkout MVCContrib.Grid or Telerik MVC Grid which have more functionality than the built-in WebGrid.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, easier than I expect: override ToString()!!!